# Changing dynamic object type at runtime

Tags: c#, dynamic, runtime

I have the following interface:

```
public interface IDynamicData: IPersistent
{
    string Name { get; }
    DataType Type { get; set; }
    string InputFormat { get; set; }
    dynamic Value { get; }
    string DisplayValue { get; }
}
```

I have a couple of classes that implement this interface, but the one I am interested in is this one:

```
public class DynamicInput : IDynamicData
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    private DataType _Type;
    public DataType Type
    {
        get { return _Type; }
        set
        {
            _Type = value;
            switch (Type)
            {
                case DataType.String:
                    Mapping = new StringMap();
                    break;
                case DataType.Numeric:
                    Mapping = new DoubleMap();
                    break;
                case DataType.DateTime:
                    Mapping = new DateTimeMap();
                    break;
                default:
                    Mapping = new StringMap();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    [Browsable(false)]
    public dynamic Value { get; private set; }
    [Browsable(false)]
    public string DisplayValue
    {
        get
        {
            return Value != null && (Type.Equals(DataType.DateTime) || Type.Equals(DataType.Numeric))
                ? Value.ToString(InputFormat)
                : Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, the key here is the `dynamic Value` property. This value is populated from a string input using the `StringMap`, `DecimalMap`, `DoubleMap` and `DateTimeMap` classes, where the key method is (similar) to this one:

```
public override dynamic ProcessInput(string input, int index, string inputFormat, double multiplier, char splitOn = ',')
    {
        _IsValid = false;
        try
        {
            _Input = input;
            double tmp;
            _IsValid = Double.TryParse(input.Split(splitOn)[index], out tmp);
            return tmp * multiplier;
        }
        catch
        {
            _IsValid = false;
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

This seesm to work fine, and I effectively have a strongly typed `Value` property at runtime (at least how I understand it). I would like to know when this definition of the type occurs though - when the object is instantiated, or when the `Value` is assigned to.

I would like to be able to let the user change the type of the `Value` property at runtime, which involves setting the `DataType` property to either `string`/`DateTime`/`double` etc. This however, sometimes results in a `RuntimeBindingException` being thrown at runtime. It doesn't happen all the time, only sometimes, which, I am assuming occurs when the `DataType` property is changed in between the `Value` property being set and the `DisplayText` property being read. That is where the error occurs, in this getter:

```
public string DisplayValue
    {
        get
        {
            return Value != null && (Type.Equals(DataType.DateTime) || Type.Equals(DataType.Numeric))
                ? Value.ToString(InputFormat)
                : Value;
        }
    }
```

I would just like to understand why this happens, and if my analysis is correct, and potentially if there are any workarounds to this problem. If its not possible then thats fine, I will lock down editing of the type of the IDynamicData object.

EDIT

I have experienced this only once - hard to replicate. The instance was, the object was created with `DataType.Numeric`. I had input strings like "12.345" coming in, every second and being parsed then assigned to the `Value` property. Then, while I am still receiving data, I changed to `DataType.String`. This is where the exception occurred. That is, `DoubleMap` was returning a "dynamic" `double`, then while input data is still coming in, the `StringMap` returned a "dynamic" `string` representation of `12.345'.

Comment: Side note: list of tags missing framework you are using (like WPF, WinForms,...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you have a value such as the string "15" but the Type property is set to, for example, DataType.Numeric.  In such a case, your code would attempt to call the parameterized overload of ToString().  Because the receiving object is a string, there is no such overload, so the binder throws an exception.

That is a bit speculative.  If you could post a working example that demonstrates the problem, or at least describe the specific values you are using when the exception is thrown, we could be more certain of its cause.

If you want to convert a string representation of a number to an int or double representation of that number, you will need to convert the actual value in the Value property.  (The actual type of the property is object, by the way, so value routes stored here will be boxed.)  The best solution for this would depend somewhat on how you want the calling code to look.

EDIT in response to your edit: the other possibility is that the Value object is a numeric data type such as double, but the Type property is DataType.String.  In that case, your code tries to return the double directly, which would cause the binder to fail, just as

```
string s = 1.2
```

would fall to compile.  In that case, you could use ToString(), thus:

```
return Value != null && (Type.Equals(DataType.DateTime) || Type.Equals(DataType.Numeric))
            ? Value.ToString(InputFormat)
            : Value.ToString();
```

That is more of a workaround than a solution, however.  I would examine the runtime type of the object and get rid of the Type property.

Comment: Thanks @phoog, The conversion from the (input) string to `dynamic` I don't think is the issue, its more the `Value.ToString()` call when getting the display text, depending on what type is returned from the parser. The `Value` property is and already parsed string into `DateTime`, `double`, `decimal` etc

Comment: @Simon there is no conversion to dynamic; you are just referencing the string (or boxed double, or what have you) in an object-type field.  You do not indicate how or when the Type property is set -- is there anything to guarantee that it is in sync with the object stored in the Value property?

Comment: @Simon try calling Value.GetType() as a diagnostic to see whether the Type property is consistent with the runtime type of the object referenced by the Value property.

Comment: @Simon sorry, I see you do indicate how the Type property is set.  If you have a double in Value, then set Type to String, then call DisplayText, you will get the runtime binder exception for the reason I described in the edit.  Using the object's actual runtime type in that getter would solve the problem.

Comment: Ah yes, I see. Thanks. I either need to synchronize the `Type` property with the actual type in `Value`, or use `GetType` when returning `DisplayText`